# Can work-energy theorem be apply in $x$ axis and $y$ axis separately?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, reference-frames, work, coordinate-systems

when we solve vector quantities like finding net acceleration of a particle moving in xy direction. we apply newton 2nd law in x axis and y axis separately to find acceleration in that direction and then apply vector sum. So, can we also apply work energy theorem in similar manner or not?

Comment: Why not just do the calculation with two different accelerations in x and y direction? and calculating the difference in kinetic energy after a time t

Answer (score 0):

No. Work and energy are scalar quantities that do not have directions. There is no x-component or y-component of potential energy, for example. It's not possible to apply vector-based math to things that aren't vectors. You can't perform a vector sum on scalars.